# How to get email sent based on word entered in cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am unable to have a email sent automatically based on cell change done by automation

```
function sendMailEdit(e) {
    var column = (typeof(column)=='READY')?column:11; 

    const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,11,11,11).getValues();

    let itemsDescription = rData[0][1];
    let serial = rData[0][2];
    let ordernumber = rData[0][5];
```

This is the code. So every time I enter anything in the speadsheet it pings a email. How to do I make it column-specific. I've tried the if command. However it works when I type the trigger work, but doesn't trigger if the trigger word is automatically added

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is incomplete it's hard to tell what you want.  But perhaps this will help.

```
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 11) {
    const rData = e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 11).getValues();
    let itemsDescription = rData[0][1];
    let serial = rData[0][2];
    let ordernumber = rData[0][5];
    //the rest of your code
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey this is almost there. Basically it doesnt trigger the email if the word is added via conditional formatting. it only works if I manually type something in.

Comment: Yes onEdit triggers are only generated for user edits